# emacs23 to emacs24: imap shell "Opening nnimap server...failed: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated ..."

Tags: linux, emacs, debian, imap

I have attempted migration from emacs23 to emacs24 on Debian/Testing (Jessie).
Imap connection via shell script have ceased to work.

Messages buffer:

```
Opening nnimap server...
Opening connection to  via shell...
Opening nnimap server...failed: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

~/.emacs

```
'(gnus-secondary-select-methods (quote ((nnimap "" 
   (nnimap-stream shell) 
   (imap-shell-program "exec /home/anfi/bin/imap")))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting imap-shell-program "globally" in ~/.gnus.el fixed the problem.

```
(setq imap-shell-program "/home/anfi/bin/imap")
```